# What's the diffience between newDate('2019-05-10') and new Date('2019/05/10')

Tags: javascript

What's the diffience between `new Date("2019-05-10")`  and `new  Date("2019/05/10")`
and why?

I mean `new Date("2019-05-10")`  and `new Date("2019/05/10")`
they are different in the console result

Comment: `new Date(2019/05/10)` === `new Date(40.38)` and `new Date(2019-05-10)` === `new Date(2004)` ... if my maths is right

Comment: `2019/05/10` is a math expression: 3 numbers are divided by each other.

Comment: you must try `new Date(2019*05*10)` ( == `new Date(100950)` ;)  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224459/how-to-create-a-date-object-from-string-in-javascript

Comment: ```new Date("2019-05-10")``` and new ```Date("2019/05/10")``` have the same date but different time in my console

Comment: I agree. The one with hyphens ends up being 00:00:00 UTC (then converted to local time), where the one with slashes is 00:00:00 in your local timezone. No idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's some inconsistencies in date parsing and I found the following excerpt in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

> Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse,
>   they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser
>   differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings
>   is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that
>   date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Comment: This explanation is consistent with the behavior I described in the comments. +1

Comment: thanks. I found that  only using the hyphens in date string  could cause the same result both in js and node

Comment: @金陆欢 well `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` is the format based on simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. And is the one followed by ECMA standard and hence would be same across different execution engines.