# Angular -- Put a custom Date in an Array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I did an array with some properties incl Date.
But the problem is that I have a " Now " Date, and I want to specify a date in Date() like : 20/10/2018 ... Not Today.

Here's the code :

```
articles = [
    {
      titre: "Mon premier Article",
      contenu:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      dateCreation: Date()
    },
    {
      titre: "Mon second Article",
      contenu:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      dateCreation: Date()
    },
    {
      titre: "Mon troisième Article",
      contenu:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      dateCreation: Date()
    }
  ];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a date object from string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224459/how-to-create-a-date-object-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Igor I tried, Not Working.

Comment: If you want more help you will have to include what you "tried". [edit] your question and add **exactly** what you tried and the result. "tried" and "not working" could both mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Working now !

I just needed to change it in the array and remove "Date ()" and put the value I wanted instead and it's done with the Date type.

Like this :

```
articles = [
    {
      titre: "Mon premier Article",
      contenu:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      **dateCreation: "2018 / 10 / 25"**
```

**Thank you all for your help !**

Comment: If you want an actual date use: `dateCreation: new Date(2018,10,25)`. If you want to store/communicate a date as a string use ISO8601 notation so the value can't be misconstrued: `dateCreation: "2018-10-25"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by initialing your date by like 
new Date('Year,Month,Day)
`date = new Date('2019','05','19')`
will return Wed Jun 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0500