# From string to date setting format

Tags: angular, date, format, date-formatting

I have a date in this format "DD/MM/YYYY" when I try `new Date("23/06/2019")` I get the following error:

> "Invalid Date"

how can I fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: See also [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7151543/215552)

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass in isn't something the Date 'constructor' knows how to deal with.
Look at how to create a date object with javascript (Here's a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224459/how-to-create-a-date-object-from-string-in-javascript)).

You can try this as a quick fix for now:

```
let yourDate = "23/06/2019".split('/');
new Date(yourDate[2], yourDate[1], yourDate[0]);
```

or

```
let yourDate = "23/06/2019".split('/').reverse().join('-');
new Date(yourDate);
```

Comment: correct your first solution, new Date(year,month,day), month are 0 to january, 1 for febrary...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the moment.js library for date parsing. You could easily parse your date string.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

moment(„23/09/2019“,“DD-MM-YYYY“)